# "Listen" button on my main post page

Tags: plugins, buttons

Peace be with you,

Please how do i place the "Listen" button on my main post page. eg: https://www.revealnews.org/recent/   do it, don't know what or how they did it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of plugins for WordPress to play stream radio. Some of them are:

[Shoutcast Icecast HTML5 Radio Player](https://srd.wordpress.org/plugins/shoutcast-icecast-html5-radio-player/)

[WordPress Live Streaming Audio Player](https://www.wonderplugin.com/wordpress-audio-player/examples/wordpress-live-streaming-audio-player-id16/)

[8 Awesome WordPress Plugins To Run Your Radio Website](https://www.sktthemes.net/wordpress-plugins/8-awesome-wordpress-plugins-run-radio-website/)

To play just an audio file, there is a number of plugins, too:

[WordPress HTML5 Audio Player Bar](https://www.wonderplugin.com/wordpress-audio-player/examples/wordpress-html5-audio-player-bar-id2/)

[Compact WordPress Audio/Music Player Plugin (All Browser Compatible)](https://www.tipsandtricks-hq.com/wordpress-audio-music-player-plugin-4556)

Comment: Sorry Sir, I don't want to stream radio. If i can play an audio file in my main or single post, how can can i play it directly from the home page in the posts column. eg: where you have "read more" you also have a "listen" or "play" button to any audio file in that post. I hope you understand now. Thank you.

Comment: I have amended my answer with links to plugins to play an audio file.